# How to use cookie with NSURLRequest to fetch JSON data from WEBserver?

Tags: ios, json, https, webserver, nsurlconnection

I am having an issue trying to fetch JSON page from one of our company's site that requires authentication.
- http://xyz.com - requires authentication
- I need to fetch data from http://xyz.com/jsonpage1 
- In View DidLoad, I send user and pwd for login to establish session 
- Then, I have a button that would request JSON.

This sequence doesn't work (meaning if the session loading code is in a different routine than the json loading code). If I have both codes in same routine like a view didLoad, then it seems to recognize my credentials and get JSON back. Strange! What am I missing? How is supposed to work? I thought establishing the session will create the cookie one time and no need to bother with it again? Am I losing the cookie somehow when I click the button?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self establishSession];
}

-(void)establishSession{   
//
//Login Session
//
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz.com/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",@"abc",@"123"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:15];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)getJSON:(id)sender
{
 NSError *error = nil;

resultsView.text =@"";

[self establishLoginSession];   //I have to have this line here to get it to work ?????

//get JSON

NSURL *jurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz.com/jsonPage1"];

NSData *jdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jurl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:jdata //1
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
resultsView.text = dataString;
}
```

```
//Not sure if I need the cookie??
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  *)response
{

NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
NSDictionary *fields = [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields];

if([fields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"])
   cookie = [fields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only make one request with a `NSURLConnection` object, so you should create it right before you're making the request.